# React: Material-ui grid is not responsive - how do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui

I am using a material-ui grid to place a chart.js chart inside so that it will be responsive when screen size changes. However on mobile size screen it looks horrible and when minimising screen on desktop looks terrible to.

Can someone please point out to me where I have gone wrong and how to make it responsive? I have looked up a few videos, articles and stack overflow posts but nothing has solved it so far.

code below:
Grid.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Grid, Paper } from "@material-ui/core";
import Chart4 from '../Components/Chart/Chart4';




//Setting up styling for the grid that we can use below
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    grid: {
        display: 'flex',
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        margin: '0px'
    },
    paper: {
        padding: theme.spacing(2),
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: theme.palette.text.seconday,
        background: theme.palette.success.light,
    }

}));



//Grid is rendered below with Chart that is imported above inside the Grid so it can be
function Grido() {
    const classes = useStyles();
  return (
      <Grid container spacing={2} className={classes.grid}  >
          <Grid item xs={12} md={12}>
                  <Chart4 />
          </Grid>
      </Grid>
  );
}

export default Grido;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import './App.css'

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch, Route, Link
} from "react-router-dom";

import {
  Drawer, List, ListItem,
  ListItemIcon, ListItemText,
  Container, Typography,
} from "@material-ui/core";

import HomeIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Home";
import InfoIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Info';
import Grido from './Grid/Grid';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  drawerPaper: { width: 'inherit', height: '100%', background: '#F7F5FB' },
  link: {
    textDecoration: 'none',
    color: theme.palette.text.primary
  }
}))

const styles = {
  paper: {
    background: "blue"
  }
}

//Setting up our material-ui drawer within React Router so can go between the two pages
//Styles are applied in the Drawer just below <Drawer
const App = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();


  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container" style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <Drawer
          style={{ width: '220px' }}
          classes={{ paper: classes.paper }}
          variant="persistent"
          anchor="left"
          open={true}
          classes={{ paper: classes.drawerPaper }}
        >
          <List>
            <Link to="/" className={classes.link}>
              <ListItem button>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <HomeIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={"Home"} />
              </ListItem>
            </Link>
            <Link to="/about" className={classes.link}>
              <ListItem button>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <InfoIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={"About"} />
              </ListItem>
            </Link>
          </List>
        </Drawer>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Container>
                <Grido />
            </Container>
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/about">
            <Container>
              <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom>
                About
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom>
                Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
              </Typography>
            </Container>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I dont if this file is relevant but just incase.
Chart.js

```
  
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import axios from "axios";
import * as ReactBootStrap from 'react-bootstrap';
import './Chart.css';

const Chart4 = () => {
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({});
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  const chart = () => {
    let Fore = [];
    let Act = [];

    axios
      .get('https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/intensity/2020-09-01T15:30Z/2020-09-10T17:00Z')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        for (const dataObj of res.data.data) {
          Fore.push(parseInt(dataObj.intensity.forecast));
          Act.push(parseInt(dataObj.intensity.actual));
        }
        setChartData({
          labels: Fore,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Carbon Intensity Levels",
              data: Act,
              backgroundColor: "#F58A07",
              borderWidth: 4
            }
          ]
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {

        setError(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsLoaded(true);  
      })

  
    console.log(Fore, Act);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    chart();
  }, []);

  if (error) {
    return  <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div> <ReactBootStrap.Spinner animation="border"/> </div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="chart">
          <Line
            data={chartData}
            options={{
              responsive: true,
              title: { text: "2020-09-01T15:30Z - 2020-09-10T17:00Z", display: true },
              scales: {
                yAxes: [
                  {
                    ticks: {
                      autoSkip: true,
                      maxTicksLimit: 100,
                      beginAtZero: true
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                      display: false
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: "Actual"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                xAxes: [
                  {
                    gridLines: {
                      display: false
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: "Forecast"
                    }

                  }
                ]
              }
            }} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }


};

export default Chart4;
```

Comment: What styles do the `className` of `App` and `chart` contain? And what if you lay another components rather than the chart?

Comment: Try to add `maintainAspectRatio: false` to the options for `Line` chart.

Comment: the className of App is left over nothing in it - but the chart className css contains this:.chart {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

Comment: @hotcakedev tried the maintainAspectRatio but doesnt help thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you are wrong. You could build this codepen. That would greatly help. And try to set `css` for `chart` class to `position: 'relative'` with or without `flex`.

Comment: @hotcakedev I am trying now but not sure if the code will work in codepen because of all the dependencies and way its structured

Comment: I think you can use this [codepen](https://codepen.io/donnyburnside/pen/XgqLEX)

Comment: And refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150094/react-js-material-ui-project-not-working-on-codepen-although-its-working-locall)